# How to modify a model in Joomla using a plugin?

Tags: plugins, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

In components/com_content/models/article.php there is a function called *storeVote* which stores votes from 0 to 5 points. This is the first line of that function:

```
if ( $rate >= 1 && $rate <= 5 && $pk > 0 )
```

The plugin I'm programming for Joomla 2.5 can store vote from 0 to 5 and 0 to 10, so I need to modify that line into:

```
if ( $rate >= 1 && $rate <= 10 && $pk > 0 )
```

automatically when the plugin is being installed.

How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

P.D.

This is the code I need to implement in Joomla, but I don't know how to implement it, any help?

```
$searchString='if ( $rate >= 1 && $rate <= 5 && $pk > 0 )';
$replaceString='if ( $rate >= 1 && $rate <= 10 && $pk > 0 )'; 
$fh = fopen("article.php", 'r+');
$file = file_get_contents('article.php');
$file = str_replace($searchString, $replaceString, $file);
fwrite($fh, $file);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to write a content plugin which hooks into the onContentPrepare() method to alter the content as desired before rendering.  Be sure to pay attention to your plugins order position in relation to other "content" plugins, as this could adversely affect expected behaviors if not accounted for.

http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_content_plugin

Comment: Can I add a the function onContentPrepare() to my plugin file? in order to do everything with just one plugin

Comment: That depends if your existing plugin is a content plugin.  There are several different "types" of plugin (content, user, authentication, system, etc..).  As long as your existing plugin is a content plugin then yes, you can; otherwise you will need to write a whole new extension.